# Почему вместо PUT запроса отправляется OPTIONS?

Tags: javascript, axios

У меня сначало было такая же ошибка с методом post, но я исправил таким образом

```
this.url.defaults.transformRequest = [(data) =>  JSON.stringify(data)]
   return this.url.post('/index.php/rest/' + post.type + '/signup',{
                "number" : post.number,
                "name" : post.name,
                "city_id" : post.city_id,
            })
```

Но с методом PUT такой вариант не подходит

На сервере указан метод put

```
Server  
"nginx/1.10.1"
[Learn More]
Date    
"Tue, 01 Aug 2017 06:19:01 GMT"
[Learn More]
Content-Type    
"application/json; charset=utf-8"
[Learn More]
Content-Length  
"41"
[Learn More]
Connection  
"keep-alive"
[Learn More]
Access-Control-Allow-Origin 
"*"
[Learn More]
access-control-allow-headers    
"Host,X-Forwarded-Proto,X-Forw…ontrol-Request-Method,Origin"
[Learn More]
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    
"POST , GET, DELETE, PUT , OPTIONS"
[Learn More]
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    
"true"
```

Вот метод put

```
function Api(url){

this.url = axios.create({
    baseURL: url,
});
}

this.url.defaults.transformRequest = [(data) =>  JSON.stringify(data)]
return this.url.put('/index.php/rest/' + type + '/signin',{
            number
        })
```

PHP код на бэкэнде

```
public function signin_put()
{
    require APPPATH . 'libraries/JWT.php';
    try{
        $this->set_response($this->user->sign_in($this->inputData->sms, $this->inputData->number));
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->set_response(array("message" => "!OK"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cначало проверяется поддерживает ли сервер `put` для этого отправляется `options`. Если `options` говорит что `put` нельзя - `put` не делается.

Comment: я понимаю, но на сервере разрешен метод put

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Methods    
"POST , GET, DELETE, PUT , OPTIONS"

Comment: В вашем примере не видно как именно вы отправляете put, и это невозможно ни повторить не проверить. Вам нужно уточнить вопрос.

Comment: this.url.defaults.transformRequest = [(data) =>  JSON.stringify(data)]
return this.url.put('/index.php/rest/' + type + '/signin',{
   number
  })

Comment: у вас случайно нет интерсепторов каких и jwt?

Comment: нет я только vue.js и axios устонавливливал

Comment: На сервере разрешите не защищенные options запросы, скорее всего preflight запрос получает 403, потому-что он отправляется без токена

Comment: А как проверить?

Comment: Там и так открыты

Comment: С postman и других сервисов нормально работает!

Comment: Artsiom , JWT есть на стороне бэканда, до этого я не знал, ведь я не писал бэкэнд